# Can't log in after removing input method

Tags: login-screen

I accidentally removed the English keyboard and replaced with Greek keyboard, then I restarted. Now I don't have the correct input method to enter the password.

Comment: Can you log in from the command line (Ctrl+Alt+F2)?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you removed English from input sources.
Worked on my PC.

- During boot choose Advanced options then recovery mode. At the following screen choose Drop to root shell prompt. Run

  ```
  su -l <user-name>
  ```

  to login as user (root does not change input methods).
  then run

  ```
  gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
  ```

the output is something like

```
[('xkb', 'gr+simple')]
```

Run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources  "[('xkb', 'us')]"
```

input source 'English US' will be added. Then

```
sudo reboot
```

- **Or from login screen**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to enter tty1.

Run:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
```

the output is something like

```
[('xkb', 'gr+simple')]
```

Run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources  "[('xkb', 'us')]"
```

input source will be added. **From tty1** Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to login screen and enter your password.

- **Or from root shell.**
  Delete the password for your user by running this command:

  ```
  passwd -d <user-name>
  ```

and

```
reboot.
```

If you ever get prompted for a password, just type enter and it should work.

Once password is removed you can log in without it, you can add input method and change password.

Comment: What is the goal of deleting the password?

Comment: First part must be good, but I don't recommend to remove password.

Comment: It's much better to change password there.